# Migration from Azure Active Directory Graph to Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation

i have a powershell script for monitoring the service principal expiry date.The script is being executed by Azure Automation(Runbook + Run as account).The "Run as account" needs Application.Read.All permissions in Azure Active Directory Graph as shown in screenshot below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi1mc.jpg]

The problem is that Microsoft retired AAD Graph and it is not anymore available as option as shown below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKZSG.png]

That means for me that i can not run anymore the script,especially i can not run these cmdlet because of the missing permissions

- get-azadapplication
- get-azadcredentials

I get the error:

```
30 |  get-azadserviceprincipal
 |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 | Insufficient privileges to complete the operation
```

I granted the same permissions in Microsoft Graph(see below) but seems not to work:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4eLR.jpg]

According to Microsoft in december starts the migration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azps-msgraph-migration-changes?view=azps-6.6.0

Would this means that after the migration with the given permissions in Graph API, the used cmdlet will work as before?Do you guys(powershell scripter) have similar issue due to migrating from AAD Graph to Microsoft Graph?

Comment: unfortunately without success even with directory.readwrite.all

Comment: may i know in run as account there must be 2 types 1 run-as-account and other will be classic . which one are you using ?

Comment: Azure Run As Account,also not the classic one

Comment: let me test it out on my environment and get back here

Answer (score 0):

I tested the same in my environment and the error was also same like below which you were getting even after adding the required API permissions :

[image]

As for the solution , Depending on the requirement you have to assign `Roles And Administrators` in the **PIM** for AzureAD as well.

**Step 1:** You can go to ***Azure Active Directory Overview*** Page >> ***Roles and Administrators*** Blade and click on ***Global Reader*** which will provide read access to everything present in Azure Active Directory.

[image]

**Step 2:** In ***Global Reader*** Page >> ***Active Assignments*** Blade >> Click on ***Add assignments***.

[image]

**Step 3:** In Add Assignments Page >> ***Select members*** >> ***Search for the Automation account run as account name*** >> ***Select*** >> ***Next*** >> ***Add Description*** >> ***Assign***

[image]
[image]

**Step 4:** Once the above is successfully done , you can run the below in automation runbook and get the required output .

```
$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
    $account = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
               -TenantId $Conn.TenantID  `
               -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID  `
               -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint
Get-AzADApplication
```

[image]

Comment: it seems that this is the solution,also Run as Account needs an Azure AD Role.However in this way i will have access (reader rights) to the whole tenant,so i can read all AZSubsriptions and this something against IT Compliance.They created a subgroup with subscriptions which i (as DEVOPS Team) am supposed to access and check.Is there any way how to assign 'global reader' rights only to this subgroup andd not to all tenant?

Comment: @olti , global reader is not for the subscriptions , its read permissions for the azure ad , even if they have restricted you to few subscriptions but the tenant will be same for all subscriptions. but still let me check if it can be limited to group only.